# Does kubernetes service of type NodePort works with worker ip or control plane(master) ip?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

Lets say I have one master(192.168.1.1) and one worker(192.168.1.2) nodes in my cluster. And if I create a service of NodePort 30001, then will it work with master IP(192.168.1.1:30001) or worker IP(192.168.1.2:30001)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service type `NodePort` opens the port on **all** the nodes of the cluster and the pods associated with the `NodePort` service can be accessible using the `IP:port` combination where `IP` represents the nodes' external IP and `port` represents the port exposed on the node for the `NodePort` service.

Quoting the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport):

> If you set the type field to NodePort, the Kubernetes control plane
> allocates a port from a range specified by --service-node-port-range
> flag (default: 30000-32767). Each node proxies that port (the same
> port number on every Node) into your Service. Your Service reports the
> allocated port in its .spec.ports[*].nodePort field.

> Note that this Service is visible as NodeIP:spec.ports[*].nodePort
> and .spec.clusterIP:spec.ports[*].port. (If the --nodeport-addresses
> flag in kube-proxy is set, would be filtered NodeIP(s).)

The [following post](https://hackernoon.com/introducing-nodeport-service-in-kubernetes-ear0360s) gives an example where the application is reachable from the master nodes `IP:port` combination as well for the `NodePort` service.

Also, the post at [openshift](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_nodeport.html#getting-traffic-into-cluster-nodeport) clearly states that ports are opened for all the nodes:

> Use NodePorts to expose the service nodePort on all nodes in the
> cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, suppose we have two worker nodes (192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3), so both of these will expose the service on their IP and the particular port, lets say as of now port 80, so both these will work:
192.168.1.2: 80 and 192.168.1.3:80

Comment: yes, that's what the doc says and I believe the requests will fail for one of them if the pod is scheduled on the other node

Comment: so as per your last comment if I have two worker nodes(192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3) and only one replica set for the deployment, and cluster choose to create the only pod on worker 1(192.168.1.2), then  worker 2 ip address wont work for this service, as this worker 2, doesnt have the pod?

Comment: now that I think of it, my last statement is not correct. Even a `NodePort` service internally routes traffic through the `ClusterIP` service and all the nodes route traffic to the `ClusterIP` and don't directly communicate with the pod. So, in your above example, the pods will be reachable from both the worker nodes `IP:port`.

Comment: this [diagram](https://miro.medium.com/max/3600/1*CdyUtG-8CfGu2oFC5s0KwA.png) gives a good idea of how the NodePort service works behind the scenes.

Comment: Got it thanks a lot :), also I need to setup an on premise kubernetes cluster and we have a custom load balancer which can redirect the traffics to multiple servers. Which tool we should use to setup the cluster or should we go through the hard way as explained in this github repo https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way

Comment: I have not setup up a Kubernetes cluster for on premises at production grade so can't really comment much. I have only used `minikube` and `kind` which I think are for development purposes only.

Comment: @VinaySorout, I gave some more reading regarding the `NodePort` service and it seems the port is exposed on master node as well. I have also added a post where it shows an example of accessing the service using the master node's IP by deploying `NodePort` service. Thanks for the question, learnt a new thing today :-)

Comment: Could you please share the link for your post!

Comment: please see the updated answer, I have added everything there.